# How can I sum the uint values ​inside the tokenRewards array?

Tags: arrays, sum, solidity

I want to get the sum of the number of rewards I have earned per token I have from this function **getCurrentTotalStakeEarned**.

```
    uint256 public tokensPerBlock;
    mapping(address => uint256) public _balances;
    mapping(address => mapping(uint256 => uint256)) public _ownedTokens;

    function getCurrentTotalStakeEarned(address targetAddress) external view returns (uint256[] memory, uint256[] memory) {
        uint256 [] memory tokenIds = new uint256[](_balances[targetAddress]); 
        uint256 [] memory tokenRewards = new uint256[](_balances[targetAddress]); 
        for(uint256 i = 0; i < _balances[targetAddress]; i++){
            tokenIds[i] = _ownedTokens[targetAddress][i];
            tokenRewards[i] = _getTimeStaked(tokenIds[i]++).mul(tokensPerBlock);
        }
        return (tokenIds, tokenRewards);
    }

    function _getTimeStaked(uint256 tokenId) internal view returns (uint256) {
        if (receipt[tokenId].stakedFromBlock == 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        return block.number.sub(receipt[tokenId].stakedFromBlock);
    }
```

With an array, I can see how much each token gives me. But I want to sum them.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICisJ.png)
I just want the values ​​I marked in red to be summed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do we want?

Total value of rewards per address.

What do we have?

An array of rewards per address returned from `getCurrentTotalStakeEarned`

We can simply iterate the array and sum the values.

```
function reduce(uint256[] arr) pure internal returns (uint256 result){
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        result += arr[i];
    }
 
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just wanted to sum the values ​​in array and I succeeded because of your code.

I added this operation to the for loop and got the total result;
`result += tokenRewards[i];`